# What does it mean to beat one's hands together?

Tags: literature, gestures

In Bram Stoker's *Dracula*, characters are described as beating their hands together (see chapters [21](http://www.sacred-texts.com/goth/drac/drac21.htm), [17](http://www.sacred-texts.com/goth/drac/drac17.htm), and [11](https://books.google.com/books?id=0WI4CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT132&lpg=PT132&dq=dracula%20beat%20hands%20together&source=bl&ots=c6jgJg8-EE&sig=ChUgrojzSeGH4Vyk8nj4bkFCcbU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBmoVChMIhNjx7NrKyAIVVtpjCh2pYwVD#v=onepage&q=dracula%20beat%20hands%20together&f=false)), typically in situations of stress or helplessness. What is this gesture? At first, I read it like "clapping", but that makes no sense in context. Is it to clasp the hands and move them up-and-down in a mime of supplication? If so, how do you do this with "open hands", as in chapter 17?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen or heard this expression before. However the sentence ...

> He grew quite hysterical, and raising his open hands, beat his palms together in a perfect agony of grief.

... seems pretty clear. I think that it must be a clapping motion but with the fingers bent back rather than cupped and the hands perfectly aligned rather than slightly crossed. That way there would not be much sound.

I don't recall ever seeing anyone doing this. Maybe I've just never seen anyone in an agony of grief.

**Update**

[Clapping Hands as a Gesture of Anguish and Anger in Mesopotamia and Israel](https://www.jtsa.edu/Documents/pagedocs/JANES/1995%2023/NFox23.pdf)

Whaddaya know?

Comment: I'm getting 'Page not found'. [This link](https://janes.scholasticahq.com/article/2401-clapping-hands-as-a-gesture-of-anguish-and-anger-in-mesopotamia-and-in-israel) might work better.

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret this to mean an action suggesting aggressive intent, as a mob might do when approaching a building they intend to sack.